# How to deploy a Meteor.js app through Galaxy without MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-galaxy

Let's say I want to build a SPA using Meteor.js but I don't need MongoDB right away and would like to add MongoDB later when I have more data, or at least set the `MONGO_URL="null"` just so I can deploy through Galaxy without the console blowing up. For now I just want/need a static site, but to also have the flexibility to make it a dynamic SPA later. Is this possible through Meteor and Galaxy?

I have combed through the Meteor docs https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html
but it doesn't seem possible through their documentation. 
https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html

This would be a great feature and thanks for any info!

Comment: Have you eliminated `mongo` from your dependency tree (i.e, require it either directly or indirectly via dependencies)? If you have, that contradicts the claim on the Galaxy Guide. If not, then your dependencies either require a DB connection or claim that they do and Galaxy relies on that claim. Why not use a free-tier database for now, as mentioned in the guide?

Comment: I hav a free tier too but had a hard time connecting it with the MongoDB connection string. If I remember correctly, Mongo says to have a Node.js client, MDG(Meteor Dev Group) says that Meteor.js 1.7 would have a client built in and  they didn't have support with what Mongo says to use i.e. ```MONGO_URL with "mongodb+srv://" but it should be just "mongodb://".``` . This is the reply from MDG and this one is the reply from Mongo ```mongodb+srv://oploguser:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-olerm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true```. One contradicts the other. So I moved to the paid tier to dev but it's $$$.